# Will removing an entity automatically update their relationships?

Tags: java, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0, relationship

Suppose the `Person` entity has a `List<Address> listOfAddresses` field which is either `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany` relationship with the `Address` entity. If I remove an `Address` with `em.remove("James's_address")`, will the `listOfAddresses` automatically get updated to remove `"James's_address"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

If you have a OneToMany, and the address table has a foreign key to the person, removing the address will work. If the person and its addresses have been loaded in the session prior to the deletion of the address, its list of addresses will still contain the deleted address. You have to maintain all the associations yourself. If the person's addresses have not been loaded yet, when they are loaded, the list won't contain the deleted address, obviously, since Hibernate won't find it in the database.

If the OneToMany uses a join table, or if it's a ManyToMany, then deleting the address without removing it from te list of addresses of all the persons referencing it will lead to an exception, since the join table will continue to reference an address that you want to delete. The foreign key constraint is what will cause the exception.